# looking for a better way to shift array of characters in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

Practicing for an upcoming test in C. Making a program to shift every letter in a string(array of characters in c).

For example if I want to shift 'a' by 3 it would be 'd'. This program works fine however it's kinda of a "brutal force" solution IMO. Any idea how to accomplish this task in a better/more elegant way? using pointers/string library functions/getchar comes to mind but I'm still a novice so not sure how to implement them.

Any idea for a better solution? looking for a guide/idea you don't need to write any code for me. Thanks in advance.

```
#define N 3

int shifter(char a[],int n,int shift,char b[]);

int main(){

 char a[N] = {'h','e','y'};
 char b[N];
 int shift = 3;
 shifter(a,N,shift,b);
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("%c",b[i]);
 }

 return 0;
}

int shifter(char a[],int n,int shift,char b[]){

 int i;

 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   if(a[i]>= 65 && a[i]<=90){
     if (a[i]+shift > 90)
       b[i] = (a[i]+shift)-26;
     }
     else b[i] = a[i]+shift;
     if (a[i]>=97 && a[i]<= 122){
      if(a[i]+shift > 122)
       b[i] = (a[i]+shift)-26;
     }
     else b[i] = a[i]+shift;
   }
 return b;

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `else b[i] = a[i]+shift; }` instead of `}
        else b[i] = a[i]+shift;`

Comment: `int shifter(` --> `char *shifter(`

Comment: Since you are passing `b` array as an argument to `shifter()`, you don't need to `return b` from `shifter()`. Also shifter is supposed to return `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer to use letter literals over numeric:

```
if (a[i] >= 'a' and a[i] <= 'z')
```

Watch your flow. Currently you have

```
if (is lower) ...
else b[i] = something;

if (is upper) ...
else b[i] = something;
```

You can combine that into a single if and avoid repeating stuff:

```
if      (is lower) b[i] = ...
else if (is upper) b[i] = ...
else               b[i] = ...
```

If you are permitted, you can also determine a character’s class by #including  and using `isupper()` and `islower()`.

Finally, you can use some modular arithmetic to simplify your expressions.

```
b[i] = ((a[i] - 'a') + shift) % 26 + 'a';
```

Personally, I'd write a function to do this:

```
char shift( char c, int shift )
```

With said function, you can have a very pretty if statement...

:O)

Comment: Note that the handling of the `else b[i] = a[i]+shift` is more than just a "don't repeat yourself" problem.  The way the OP's code is structured if `a[i]` is lowercase, then the second `else b[i] = a[i]+shift` will occur and there's no handling of any possible wrap there, so some lowercase letters will get transformed into a non-letter. Apparently that's not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the feedback, I tried to apply it to solving the same problem I posted initially except this time using pointer arithmetic. It functions as intended, hopefully it is improved and could help someone else in the future.

define N 3

int i;

void pointer_shift(char *a,int shift);

int main(){

```
char a[N] = {'A','b','c'};
int shift = 3;
pointer_shift(a,shift);
return 0;
```

}

void pointer_shift(char *a,int shift) {

```
char b[N];
char *p = a;
char *q = b;

for(p=a;p<a+N;p++,q++)

{
    if(*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')
        {
            *q = ((*p-'a')+ shift)%26+'a';
            printf("%c",*q);
        }

    else if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z')
        {
            *q = ((*p-'A')+ shift)%26+'A';
             printf("%c",*q);
        }

    else { printf(" Error: Not a Letter \n"); break;}

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

the 'tr' program, which would have to be executed from the shell (or by calling `system()` from a C program) would do it easily.